# Angular: Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schem

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, packages

Comecei a ter esse erro no meu app em angular 7, já tentei remover a pasta de módulos, instalar, remover o cache e nada, o erro permanece.

> Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a
>   configuration object that does not match the API schema. -
>   configuration.entry should be one of these: function | object { :
>   non-empty string | [non-empty string] } | non-empty string |
>   [non-empty string] -> The entry point(s) of the compilation. Details:
>   * configuration.entry should be an instance of function -> A Function returning an entry object, an entry string, an entry array or a
>   promise to these things. * configuration.entry['styles'] should be a
>   string. -> The string is resolved to a module which is loaded upon
>   startup. * configuration.entry['styles'] should not contain the item
>   'C:\Users\smoreira\Documents\projetos\oficiais\doc-translator-front\node_modules\angular-bootstrap-md\scss\mdb-free.scss'
>   twice. * configuration.entry should be a string. -> An entry point
>   without name. The string is resolved to a module which is loaded upon
>   startup. * configuration.entry should be an array: [non-empty string]
>   WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack
>   has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match
>   the API schema. - configuration.entry should be one of these: function
>   | object { : non-empty string | [non-empty string] } | non-empty
>   string | [non-empty string] -> The entry point(s) of the compilation.
>   Details: * configuration.entry should be an instance of function -> A
>   Function returning an entry object, an entry string, an entry array or
>   a promise to these things. * configuration.entry['styles'] should be a
>   string. -> The string is resolved to a module which is loaded upon
>   startup. * configuration.entry['styles'] should not contain the item
>   'C:\Users\smoreira\Documents\projetos\oficiais\doc-translator-front\node_modules\angular-bootstrap-md\scss\mdb-free.scss'
>   twice. * configuration.entry should be a string. -> An entry point
>   without name. The string is resolved to a module which is loaded upon
>   startup. * configuration.entry should be an array: [non-empty string]
>   at webpack
>   (C:\Users\smoreira\Documents\projetos\oficiais\doc-translator-front\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:31:9)
>   at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable.obs [as _subscribe]
>   (C:\Users\smoreira\Documents\projetos\oficiais\doc-translator-front\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\webpack-dev-server\index.js:37:37)
>   at Observable._trySubscribe
>   (C:\Users\smoreira\Documents\projetos\oficiais\doc-translator-front\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:44:25)
>   at Observable.subscribe
>   (C:\Users\smoreira\Documents\projetos\oficiais\doc-translator-front\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:30:22)
>   at
>   C:\Users\smoreira\Documents\projetos\oficiais\doc-translator-front\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeTo.js:22:31 at Object.subscribeToResult
>   (C:\Users\smoreira\Documents\projetos\oficiais\doc-translator-front\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeToResult.js:10:45)
>   at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub
>   (C:\Users\smoreira\Documents\projetos\oficiais\doc-translator-front\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:82:29)
>   at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext
>   (C:\Users\smoreira\Documents\projetos\oficiais\doc-translator-front\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:76:14)
>   at MergeMapSubscriber._next
>   (C:\Users\smoreira\Documents\projetos\oficiais\doc-translator-front\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:59:18)
>   at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next
>   (C:\Users\smoreira\Documents\projetos\oficiais\doc-translator-front\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
>   at TapSubscriber._next
>   (C:\Users\smoreira\Documents\projetos\oficiais\doc-translator-front\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\tap.js:65:26)
>   at TapSubscriber.Subscriber.next
>   (C:\Users\smoreira\Documents\projetos\oficiais\doc-translator-front\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
>   at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext
>   (C:\Users\smoreira\Documents\projetos\oficiais\doc-translator-front\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:92:26)
>   at InnerSubscriber._next
>   (C:\Users\smoreira\Documents\projetos\oficiais\doc-translator-front\node_modules\rxjs\internal\InnerSubscriber.js:28:21) at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next
>   (C:\Users\smoreira\Documents\projetos\oficiais\doc-translator-front\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
>   at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext
>   (C:\Users\smoreira\Documents\projetos\oficiais\doc-translator-front\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:92:26)

package.json

```
{
  "name": "translate-doc-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.1",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^2.13.3",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.7.40",
    "@webpack-cli/init": "^0.1.3",
    "angular-bootstrap-checkbox": "^0.5.0",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^7.1.1",
    "angular-dropdown-component": "^1.0.8",
    "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "core-js": "^2.6.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "~2.0.8",
    "ngx6-breadcrumbs": "0.0.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.11.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.14",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "install": "^0.12.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1"
  }
}
```

Agradeço contribuições

Comment: olá, vc teria esse código no github? Ou teria como disponibilizar o arquivo webpack.config.js na pergunta, por favor?

Comment: olá, coloquei o package.json ali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução foi remover todo o projeto, criar um novo, e ir adicionando as dependências uma a uma.